# Does jQuery.css() always return 'none' when property is not set in stylesheet?

Tags: jquery, css, return-value

Just want to be sure.

Given the following:

```
if( ! ( jQuery(slider).css('max-height') == 'none') )
  return 200;
else
  ...carry on...
```

Can I always assume that if a CSS property is not set in the stylesheet that the .css() method will always return 'none'? It doesn't say so in the jQuery docs but it -seems- like it does. If there's a more standardised way to do this, please let me know. Thanks.

Comment: each CSS element has a default applied by the browser's stylesheet

Comment: So that implies that the default for 'max-height' is 'none' but it might be 'auto' or '0' for another property? Is there a standard way to determine if a property is explicitly set? (ie. not using the default)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the default for `max-height` is `none`. Hence, your condition is valid.

but, for example the default for `z-index` is `auto`. So, you have to handle each CSS property by its default value.

Comment: Probably stupid question, but... Is there a W3C document which gives these values? If so, where is it?

Comment: this jsFiddle might help, you can add on things as you need it => http://jsfiddle.net/8UbXy/. and @jchwebdev, there are standards, and there are browsers, but to say all browsers are based on standards would be a l-IE.

Comment: I'm wondering how safe my example is for long-term use. IOW: Is 'none' likely to change in the near future? OR... is there a -better- (standard) method I can use to determine whether -any- property is explicitly set? That's really what I'm looking for. THANKS!

Comment: @jchwebdev - i think checking for the css attribute should be enough & I think trying to see if a property is explicitly set would be an overkill if that's even possible. I'm not sure if there is such a way though.